# Replacing the character by deli meter based on length in SED script

Tags: regex, sed

I want to achieve following things in sed script. I tried with greedy operator  it does not works as i expected. for reference

```
:loop
s#\(S\)\(.\)\(.*R\)#-\n\1\3\n#
t loop
s#SR#--#
s#\n##g
```

If the pattern has  FlowerR  this should be replaced by number -------

If the  pattern hash   FoR     this should be replaced by  ---

So the number replace character is equal to matched pattern length which between F and R

Comment: deli meter could be any things ,, replacement has to happen for S to R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo "a FloweR has FaR FeweR FlaiR" | perl -pe 's{F.*?R}{"-" x length $&}eg'
a ------ has --- ----- -----
```

Comment: not sed, but a great answer, as are most of yours. Congrats on your 10K ;-)

Comment: This solution only  i need but in sed script